# GMock: Capture a reference argument in a mocked function

Tags: unit-testing, googletest, googlemock

I have a mocked function that has a reference argument:

```
MOCK_METHOD(func, void(MyObj &obj);
```

I'd like to capture obj into a variable so that I can call methods on it in the unit tests. So something like:

```
MyObj *capturedObj;
EXPECT_CALL(foo, func(testing::_)).WillOnce(<capture arg into capturedObj>);
capturedObj->bar();
```

How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 3):

One possible way to do that is to invoke a separate test function that will capture the argument(s) for you.

This can be done with the Invoke() action, as described in the [documentation](https://github.com/google/googlemock/blob/master/googlemock/docs/CheatSheet.md#using-a-function-or-a-functor-as-an-action):

> **Invoke(f)**     Invoke f with the arguments passed to the mock function, where f can be a global/static function or a functor.
>
> **Invoke(object_pointer, &class::method)** Invoke the method on the object with the arguments passed to the mock function.

In your case, something like the following code should work:

```
// Globally, outside your test case
MyObj *capturedObj;

void captureObj(MyObj &obj) {
    captured = &obj;
}

// [..]

// In your test case
EXPECT_CALL(foo, func(testing::_)).WillOnce(testing::Invoke(captureObj));
capturedObj->bar();
```

If you use test fixtures, `capturedObj` and `captureObj` can be class members, and you need to update the syntax as follows:

```
  EXPECT_CALL(foo, func(testing::_)).WillOnce(testing::Invoke(this, &TestFixtureClass::captureObj));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can write a [custom action](https://google.github.io/googletest/reference/actions.html#defining-actions) for it:

```
ACTION_P(SaveArgAddress, p) {
  p = &arg0;
}
```

then use that action.

But be aware that `capturedObj` will be initialized only when you run your code under test and only if the EXPECT_CALL actually matches a call - *not* right after you execute the `EXPECT_CALL` macro.

Comment: error: no return statement in function returning non-void

Comment: If your method returns a value, you'll need to combine this with a `Return` action using `DoAll`.

Comment: Latest version of googletest seems to make `p` const, so I had to do `*p = ...` and use `SaveArgAddress(&...)`